# How can I validate a date in Python 3.x?

Tags: python, validation, date, python-3.x

I would like to have the user input a date, something like:

```
date = input('Date (m/dd/yyyy): ')
```

and then make sure that the input is a valid date.  I don't really care that much about the date format.

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use the [`time` module's `strptime()`](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.strptime) function:

```
import time
date = input('Date (mm/dd/yyyy): ')
try:
  valid_date = time.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%Y')
except ValueError:
  print('Invalid date!')
```

Note that in Python 2.x you'll need to use `raw_input` instead of `input`.

Comment: Or you can use the `datetime` module's `strptime` function.  `datetime.datetime.strptime( date, "%m/%d/%Y" )`.

Answer (score 3):

```
def validDate(y, m, d):
  Result = True
  try:
    d = datetime.date(int(y), int(m), int(d))
  except ValueError, e:
    Result = False
  return Result
```

and in the program use the function defined previously:

```
 if not validDate(year_file, month_file, day_file):
   return 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Max S.,

Thanks for the code.  Here is how I implemented it:

```
while True:
    date = input('Date (m/dd/yyyy): ')
        try:
            date = time.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%Y')
            break
        except ValueError:
            print('Invalid date!')
            continue
```