# how do i write a statement if there is a character or negative in the date string?

Tags: python, date

this is what I'v done so far. I'm new to python. what I want to know is how to get an invalid date when a character is present in the date string. such as 01/x1/2012
also if a negative number is input for the date, to print out invalid date.
not using imports or calendars

```
dateStr = input("Date: ")
monthStr, dayStr, yearStr = dateStr.split("/")

months = ["January", "February","March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August","September","October", "November","December"]
monthStr = months[int(monthStr)- 1]


print ("The date is:", monthStr, dayStr+",", yearStr)

if chr in dateStr:
    print("Invalid date")
```

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216250/how-can-i-validate-a-date-in-python-3-x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These things are usually much easier done with `datetime`:

```
import datetime
date_str = input("Date: ")
try:
    date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_str,'%m/%d/%Y')
except ValueError:
    print ("Bad date")
```

---

without datetime:

```
def parse_date(date_str):
    pieces = date_str.split('/')
    try:
        for piece in pieces:
           assert int(piece) > 0
    except (ValueError,AssertionError):
        print ("Bad Date")
    else:
        print ("Good date")

parse_date('01/x1/2010')   #Bad Date
parse_date('01/-1/2010')   #Bad Date
parse_date('01/01/2010')   #Good date
```

Comment: well i am trying to avoid using import for now. I want to know how to do it without using import or calendars

Comment: Keep in mind with this solution; you aren't checking for _valid_ dates, just that the string has numbers and `/`. So it will mark as valid stuff like `100/20/30`. It is not clear that this is part of the  exercise or not.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid -- Yeah, I thought about that.  but OP only said removing things which were negative and didn't have numbers ... It wouldn't be *that* difficult to modify to check for valid dates.  Just unpack the split:  `month,day,year = date_str.split('/')` and then use a series of asserts instead of the loop:  `assert (1 >= int(month) >= 12)` and so on ...

Answer (score 0):

I would say, parse the date with a regex for validity. To get you started, this regex would match any date in xx/xx/xxxx format where x is a number

```
/d{1,2}//d{1,2}//d{4}
```

You can customize your regex your and check for a valid match.

**Edit**: Looks like using datetime is a better idea