# how to validate a date in python

Tags: python, date

hi i would like to validate some date in python. but the problem is that i have a praticular range, for example, my date goes from `1/1/2014`to `08/07/2014` . So my question is how do i validate both the format and the value. i looked at this link but it only validates the format but not the specific values.

```
import time
date = input('Date (mm/dd/yyyy): ')enter date here
try:
    valid_date = time.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%Y')
except ValueError:
    print('Invalid date!')
```

[How can I validate a date in Python 3.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216250/how-can-i-validate-a-date-in-python-3-x)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than use `time.strptime()`, use `datetime.datetime.strptime()` and then validate the resulting object to be within your range:

```
from datetime import datetime, date
date_input = input('Date (mm/dd/yyyy): ')
try:
    valid_date = datetime.strptime(date_input, '%m/%d/%Y').date()
    if not (date(2014, 1, 1) <= valid_date <= date(2014, 8, 7)):
        raise ValueError('Date out of range')
except ValueError:
    print('Invalid date!')
```

If no exception is thrown, `valid_date` is bound to a [`datetime.date()` instance](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date).

Comment: in your testing(if not) does the order matter? like isnt supposed to be date(1,1,2014)? just curious

Comment: @user3841581: The `date()` constructor always takes `year, month, day` as the arguments; see the linked documentation.

Comment: i tested it and i am having a problem:TypeError: 'str' object is not callable . what i did is that input: 1/1/2014 but that is the error i got

Comment: using `date` as a variable name?

Comment: @user3841581: then you are using `date` as a variable name elsewhere in your code and have rebound the name to a string somewhere.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: ick, indeed. Corrected.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: or is it a facade to make you *think* I am?

Comment: @MartijnPieters, we can settle on  pyborg!

Comment: @Martijn Pieters yes i did. it is now working. Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

I would like to suggest putting this into a function:

```
from datetime import datetime


def validate_date(input_date, first=datetime(2014, 1, 1),
                              last=datetime(2014, 8, 7),
                              fmt='%m/%d/%Y'):
    """Return a validated datetime.datetime or None.

    If the date has the wrong format return None, or if it is not in
    the range [first,last] also return None.  Otherwise return the
    input_date as a datetime.datetime object.

    """
    try:
        d = datetime.strptime(input_date, fmt)
        if not (first <= d <= last):
            raise ValueError
    except ValueError:
        return None
    else:
        return d


# Example usage...
valid_date = validate_date(input('Date mm/dd/yyyy: '))
if valid_date is not None:
    print(valid_date)
else:
    print('Date not ok!')
```

Comment: what does this function return? i would like to input a string with a date format and return turn if it is the correct format and within the specified range and false if not.

Comment: Updated solution with more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

```
import datetime

inputDate = input("Enter the date in format 'dd/mm/yy' : ")

day,month,year = inputDate.split('/')

isValidDate = True
try :
    datetime.datetime(int(year),int(month),int(day))
except ValueError :
    isValidDate = False

if(isValidDate) :
    print ("Input date is valid ..")
else :
    print ("Input date is not valid..")
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could explain how this code solves the issue with a couple sentences of explanation.