# how to use multiple boolean operators with list

Tags: python

I am fairly new to coding but stuck on one of these exercises;

"Write a program that accepts a date in the format DD/MM/YYYY and output whether
or not the date is valid. For example 20/07/1969 is valid, but 31/09/2012 is not."

My attempt at this:

```
d = int(input("Enter a day"))
m = int(input("Enter a month"))
y = int(input("Enter a year"))

if d > 30 and m == [4, 6, 9, 11]:
     print("This date is invalid")

elif d > 31:
     print ("This date is invalid")

elif m != [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]:
     print ("This date is invalid")

else:
     print("This date is valid")
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this is appreciated

Comment: I would use the `date` object of the `datetime` module. Probably not allowed, but here you also have to take leap years into account, etc. and some calendars even changed through time, making it very hard to parse it correctly without any error. For example, before 8 BC, a leap year took place every three years.

Comment: What is probably also missing is the fact that you get one string, separated with slashes, and thus you have to "split" it into three parts.

Comment: check this so [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25465144/how-to-validate-a-date-in-python) .

Answer (score 2):

You were close. Just modifying your code, the correct implementation of checking an entry `m` against multiple options, it would look like the following.  To check for multiple options, you use `in`, for ex. `if m in [4, 6, 9, 11]` instead of `==`.

```
if d > 30 and m in [4, 6, 9, 11]:
     print("This date is invalid")
elif d > 31:
     print ("This date is invalid")
elif m not in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]:
     print ("This date is invalid")
else:
     print("This date is valid")
```

Answer (score 1):

To check membership in a list, use the `in` operator.

```
if d > 30 and m in [4, 6, 9, 11]:
```