# How do I check date of birth format is correct

Tags: python, format, account

I'm currently coding an account signup on python and I need the user to enter their date of birth in the format DD/MM/YYYY.

How would I be able to check in the code if the input is valid or not?

```
dob=input("Enter your date of birth in the format DD/MM/YYYY")
```

Comment: Try and parse it and see if it raises an exception

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16870663/how-do-i-validate-a-date-string-format-in-python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I validate a date in Python 3.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216250/how-can-i-validate-a-date-in-python-3-x)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import datetime

try:
    date_of_birth = datetime.datetime.strptime(dob, "%d/%m/%Y")
except:
    print("Incorrect date!")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use following code

```
from datetime import datetime
i = str(raw_input('date'))
try:
    dt_start = datetime.strptime(i, '%d/%m/%Y')
except ValueError:
    print "Incorrect format"
```

Comment: `raw_input()` returns a string, so there's no use in calling `str(raw_input())`

Answer (score 0):

Try using the datetime library

```
from datetime import datetime  
def validate(date_text):
        try:
            datetime.datetime.strptime(date_text, '%d/%m/%Y')
        except ValueError:
            raise ValueError("Incorrect data format, should be YYYY-MM-DD")
```